# Problem debugging project built with scons in qtcreator 2.2

Tags: gdb, mingw, qt-creator, custom-build-step

I'm currently working on a project using SCons as build system. Since the project is written for gcc and I'm developing on Windows I'm compiling with mingw and develop in QTCreator. Therefore I have set it up as a [generic project](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-snapshot/creator-project-generic.html). Until recently I used QTCreator 2.0.1, where everything was working just fine (meaning compiling, running and debugging), but now I decided to upgrade by installing the newest qt sdk release, so I'm working on QTCreator 2.2.0. Now compiling and executing of my project is still working nicely, but the debugger is giving me trouble.

When I now try to start the project in debug mode, I get warning that the optimal debug engine for the executable of type x86-windows-msvc2008-pe-32bit is not availible and it will use Gdb instead. Sometimes debugging works fine in spite of this, but most of the time it continues with an error that my executable is "not in executable format: file format not recognized". Using my old QTCreator 2.0.1 the debugging is still working perfectly.

Now my questions are: 
Why is it trying to debug a msvc2008 executable when I compiled with mingw (and set the toolchain for the project to mingw to (even though that should be ignored for building))?
When it's trying to use gdb, what is the "not in executable format: file format not recognized" error message trying to tell me?
And most importantly: How do I need to configure QT Creator 2.2 to make debugging of mingw compiled generic projects work?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: At some point QtCreator stopped to provide built-in gdb with python helpers, you may want to download it separately and give it a try - http://origin.releases.qt-project.org/gdb/